# Do I need AWS S3 instead the "uploads" folder located in my Node.js container which is hosted by AWS ECS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, stream

I have a REST API Express.js server running on a Docker container and hosted by AWS ECS, this server accepts media uploads (photos and videos) by different clients, and currently the files system of this server contains an "uploads" folder that stores, obviously, the uploaded media by the clients. Accepting and filtering the uploaded media is done using Multer and stuff... I'm about to implement a simple video on-demand streaming service for the clients (I think that this is easy after watching a YouTube tutorial, link in the bottom).

My question is should I use AWS S3 (and Lambda I think) instead of the current approach?
my concerns for the long term are:

- costs
- scalability

and for the short term: I'm more satisfied with the current approach because I don't need to learn new technologies like Lambda functions and the other AWS services needed.

by the way I'm planning to implement [this approach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjBLbXUuyWg&ab_channel=AbdisalanCodes), do you think this way is efficient and scalable enough compared to S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De-coupling storage and your business logic is not only a **good practice**, but also it has **many benefits**, such as:

- not running out of space in your container
- highly available and redundant data storage in S3
- ability to horizontally scale your ECS service and load balance it
- availability of your files to be processed by other applications
- easy backup of your media files